# FPDF - PHP While loop only returns first value

Tags: php, pdf, loops, while-loop, fpdf

I have this code:

```
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $pdf=new PDF();
  $pdf->AliasNbPages();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(42,10, "".$row["firstname"].$row["lastname"]);
  $pdf->Output();
  }
```

It only generates the first value of the result (1 pdf page). There are supposed to be 9 results or pdf pages. In this case where the first and last name of all the players appear in 9 seperate pdf pages.

I tried the following PHP way but it did not work either.

```
while () {

 } echo "":
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be what you are after

```
  $pdf = new PDF();
  $pdf->AliasNbPages();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $pdf->AddPage();
      $pdf->Cell(42, 10, $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["lastname"]);
  } 

  $pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It did show all the players but on the same page. How can I rearrange them so that a page gets created for every player?

Comment: @user1155174 I've updated the answer. See, the code inside the while loop is executed for each pass. Moving the `addPage()` inside does create a separate page for each item iterated over.

Comment: Nvm I found a way. I just transfered the 'Addpage' inside the while loop.